# Importing .ico file

Tags: import

When I try to import any *.ico* file, I get the following error

```
IcNames = FileNames[{"*.ico"}, "c:\\Users\\gal\\Documents\\D0\\ikone\\"];
Import[IcNames[[26]]  ]
```

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Does this work? `Import["ExampleData/mathematica3.ico"]`? What version of Mathematica are you running?

Comment: It works. Looks like it works for small icons, but I'm not sure. I'm using 12.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Mathematica's importer for .ico files doesn't implement the latest standard. Specifically, it doesn't support [images in PNG format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)#PNG_format). Luckily, PNG files are embedded in their entirety, so it is quite straightforward to patch the .ico importer to support PNG files:

```
Quiet@ImportString["", "ICO"];
Begin["System`Convert`ICODump`"];
Once[
 DownValues@`ImportIconResource = DownValues@`ImportIconResource /.
    w_Which :> If[`width == 169478669,
      SetStreamPosition[`strm, Last@`entry];
      `data = ImportByteArray[ByteArray@BinaryReadList[`strm, "Byte", `entry[[-2]]], "PNG"];
      Sow[ImageData@`data, "Data"];
      Sow[ImageDimensions@`data, "ImageSize"],
      w
      ];
 ]
End[];
```

This works by patching the relevant definition `` System`Convert`ICODump`ImportIconResource ``:

- We are only interested in the part of the code handling the individual data blocks, as the header is read properly. This means we can add our patch after the header of the data block has been read
- First, we check whether the first 8 bytes of the data block match the PNG signature. We only check the last 4 bytes (which are stored into `width`) since the first 4 are discarded, but since `width` should never be bigger than 256, this shouldn't pose any issues.
- If we have a PNG entry, we simply read the relevant part of the file and pass it to `ImportByteArray`, and interpret it as a PNG.
- Finally, we extract the dimensions and image data
- If the data are in the BMP format, we don't need to do anything, and can simply use the existing code

Before and after the fix:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works.